# VNC supporting VPN tunnel?

Tags: vpn, vnc, tunnel, packet-loss

We have a number of users who have been remoting in via VPN and none have had any issues until now. One user is having an issue that we've determined to be due to packet loss or his connection dropping for less than 2 seconds at a time causing his software to kick him off but leave him connected to the VPN. When trying to troubleshoot this we ran a VNC connection to his computer and watched him for over 4 hours. He had 0 problems in this time and as soon as we disconnected he had 3 occurrences in under 30 minutes. The next day we tried again with the same results.

I've been researching into whether or not a VNC session would be able to support a VPN tunnel like that and haven't found any grounds for it. Has anyone heard of anything similar before?